# First Post Review Options Limited

Tags: support

Are there rep levels assoicated with actions on first posts? I'm at 1498 at the moment and can only leave the post as is, add a comment, and skip. With Triage, I can say it needs edits or that it is a lost cause.  If, for example, I come across a spam post as a first post, what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### There's plenty to do

You can do plenty of things in the first posts queue like vote up or down, edit, comment, flag, and view the question.

### First posts isn't triage

You just can't do some of the same things that you can do in triage, because you aren't triaging posts.

There are things in the first posts queue that you can't do in triage because those things are not necessary for triaging questions.

### Focus

Review queues are limited in different ways to keep you focused on different tasks. Some actions many not be conducive to certain tasks.

In triage, it is important to make quick decisions to categorize questions based on their level of need. If it needs to be closed, it goes to the close queue. If it needs to be edited, it goes to the improvement queue. If it is fine as it is, it goes live.

In first posts however, the focus is for you to help a new user with their first post. This means editing if necessary, voting appropriately, and commenting to offer advice or request clarifications.

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

Comment: Useful information and I do work the other queue's. So if I see span in a first post, shold I just skip it assuming it will get caught later on?

Comment: You have the option to flag posts in the first posts queue, so if you see spam there then you should flag it as spam.

Comment: I looked at some first posts and didn't see any way to flag it. Is it after you do an edit? Does it have to do with my level: 1498?

Comment: Nevermind, I found it.

Comment: Oh sorry, saw your comment on my phone, forgot to check on the computer.