# Disable skip button when some action was taken

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, review-queues, user-interface

I often do reviews on my tablet. When reviewing first posts or late answers it happens now and then it happens that after voting and/or flagging I  accidentally touch `Skip` instead of `Done`. Since `Done` is enabled not before  some action was taken, I suggest that `Skip` should be disabled on the same event.

Comment: I suggest there should be a prompt telling asking you if you want to skip the post similar to when asking a question and try to go back to home page. Otherwise you could be stuck on a post wondering why you can't skip it because you have voted on the page. You should also consider that sometimes a vote or flag is the only action the OP will want to do on  a post.

Comment: I haven't done it on phone, but one thing you can do is go to your review history and show the skipped reviews. You can then review those if you had a change of heart. This is ofc less than ideal, but it's better than nothing. The browser back button does work, but idk on mobile.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are situations when it is reasonable to use Skip after acting on a post. For example, if a post shown in review is spam, I will flag it as such and then click Skip so that it stays in review and gets more spam flags from other reviewers.

Another scenario: I can see that an answer is a really bad answer (and so I downvote it) but am not sure if it qualifies for deletion via VLQ flags. So, having downvoted it, I leave it up to next reviewer to decide if it should be flagged.

As [Servy wrote on this topic before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/352569),

> there may certainly be cases where you see something that you can do without being able to do the thing that the review queue actually sent you there for.

Comment: I never knew that if I click `Done` the post is removed from the queue - I always thought there's the need for three reviewers as in Triage. But given that, the scenarios you've described are indeed reasonable. Perhaps the help text for the buttons could mention these.

Comment: If you're flagging as spam, you're not exactly skipping. Seems like a UI problem (there's probably a feature request here somewhere).

Comment: I also thought the post was never removed from the triqge queue until having three similar review. Three "looks ok" = correct question. Three "should be closed" = question closed. But it looks like first post review are different. Triage : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue/295674#295674 , First Post : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334257/first-post-review-options-limited

Comment: But i haven't found any help center about reviewing, how does the mechanic works? Nothing like an official help page for reviewing.

Comment: @ThomasSchremser Depends on the queue. In First Posts, one click on "Done" means the review is done. In most other queues one needs more decisions than that.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the (useful, but admittedly obscure) use-case that [ol' slim mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359837/disable-skip-button-when-some-action-was-taken/359913#359913), there are a couple more boring reasons why this would be inadvisable:

1. You may not actually be done. The review interface for First Posts (and late answers) allows you to take multiple actions on a given post. It even recognizes actions you've taken on the post *prior to seeing it in review*. Just because you (say) upvoted a comment under the post doesn't necessarily mean you consider your work done (or have any desire to review the post itself at all, for that matter). Even if you do intend to eventually review the post, skip lets you "save it for later" and [return to it from your review history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221134/can-our-review-history-also-list-the-items-we-have-skipped) (not usually practical on Stack Overflow, but a heavily requested feature on some other sites).
2. It's just plain confusing. Even without the button, you could always close the tab, hit back, click another link... There's nothing actually *forcing* you to review a given task. Disabling "Skip" sends a weird message, like we're trying to lock you into your decision.

I kinda mentioned this above already, but... Skip doesn't actually block you from reviewing. If you hit it by mistake, just hit your browser's back button and hit the Done button (or whatever you intended to click) instead.