# QOL Improvement to the Low Quality Post Queue

Tags: feature-request, low-quality-posts

A small recommendation to the Low Quality Post queue, that would make reviewing a bit easier:

If I upvote a comment that was placed directly from the "Recommend Deletion" button, the buttons should grey out with an "I'm Done" like they do in the First Posts Queue, and automatically recommend the post for deletion. Will save a click and an extra (unneeded) review:

[image]

Comment: In the first posts queue upvoting a comment lets you say that you're done simply because upvoting any comment is considered an action that lets you claim to have "reviewed" that post.  The LQP queue requires you to explicitly say that the post does, or doesn't, merit deletion, to "review" the post.

Comment: But if I agree with a comment that was made, which would be something that would warrant a deletion, why shouldn't the decision to merit deletion be automatic?

Comment: Edit is also a valid review action.

Comment: @FrankerZ I think it's reasonable to require people to be explicit in saying that they personally think that the question should be deleted, and why, rather than assuming that just because they've upvoted a comment that they're willing to sign their name to deleting the post.

Comment: somewhat related: [Disable skip button when some action was taken](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359837/839601)