# Why can I skip a review item after I edit it?

Tags: support, bug

I was going through the First Posts review queue and noticed that both the <kbd>Skip</kbd> button and the <kbd>I'm Done</kbd> button were highlighted. The <kbd>No Action Needed</kbd> button was grayed out, since I edited the question.

So there were two options:

- Press <kbd>I'm Done</kbd> which moves me to the next item and increment my review count, or
- Press <kbd>Skip</kbd> which also moves me to the next item but doesn't increment my review count.

What is the point of having the <kbd>Skip</kbd> button still available? It does not seem to revert any actions I took on the review item (like remove my edits or retract any raised flags). So would it just not count as a reviewed item?

Also, if I **do** press <kbd>Skip</kbd> and go back to the review item I just skipped, all buttons are highlighted. So now I can even press <kbd>No Action Needed</kbd>.

Is this behavior intended, and if so, why? Or is this a bug?

Comment: Skip still makes sense when you first edit the post (fix grammar, spelling), but then notice that you domain knowledge is not good enough to judge whether this posts contains enough information. Reverting the edit wouldn't make sense since it's a valid edit which improves the post, but it should stay in the queue.

Comment: How do you go back to the review if you press "Skip"? Using the browser back button or finding the review in your history and then load it?

Comment: @Scratte By using the browser back button. Or rather the back button on my mouse, which I think is just a macro for the browser back button.

Comment: I see. The back button is probably not the best for getting a fresh view on the review. When you use it, hit refresh on the review as well. That should remove the "No actions needed", since Stack remembers any action you took on a review. I've noticed this if I see a post, and then vote on it, move to some other post, and then hit the back button. Then the loaded page does not see my vote showing the orange triangle, but it will with refresh.

Comment: @Scratte I actually only use the back button in the edit queue to see if what others thought of the review item (whether they rejected or approved it and why). I'll keep in mind to refresh it after going back. However, the "No actions needed" button did still work, as in, I pressed it (to test whether it did something) and it moved me to the next item, leaving the previous with the status "No actions needed".

Comment: That is very unfortunate, since you did perform an action on it. I do not see a "No actions needed" in the edit queue. I see a "Looks OK" in that. Which is now confusing me since your post here is about the "First Posts" queue. When you test it, you should go back to it to see if it has registered two separate review actions from you. I only ever "go back" using the history page myself. Please note that you can get review suspended for using "No actions needed" if action is needed.

Comment: @Scratte Yes, that is unfortunate indeed. I know I can get a suspension, it was just for testing purposes this time. It is a bit unfortunate that it is possible to do mark it as "No actions needed" while you did preform an action, even though this probably will never happen like I reproduced it. I don't really know how I can see my actions if I "go back". Is there a way to review the actions I did to the post? The queue is locked now, since I reviewed 40 items already.

Comment: The only way I know of is to hit refresh. Then you'll know you've performed an action on the post if the "I'm Done" button is active. The "No actions needed" should no longer be active in the First Posts queue. With the Suggested edit queue, you should be able to review it again when refreshing the review unless you've already reviewed it. Editing shouldn't be possible unless you're circumventing the review process, but that will automatically reject the suggested edit and render the review "no longer reviewable". Hitting back is not a good option unless you're loading a static page.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/359913

Comment: @Scratte Okay that makes sense, I'll try that tomorrow when I can review again, thanks. I didn't know about the edit part, good to know.

Comment: @BillTür Thanks, that explains the first part of my question, like BDL's answer did as well.

Comment: @Scratte "Back button" problem solved, refreshing the page will indeed not allow me to press "No actions needed". Still weird that SO allows you to press it and give a command to the server that there is no actions needed, but I can work with that. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In First Posts, I find having <kbd>Skip</kbd> available even after I have performed an action to be helpful.

The key difference is:

- <kbd>Skip</kbd> leaves the post in the queue for another reviewer to see
- <kbd>I'm Done</kbd> completes the review task and no other reviewer will see the post in that queue. An entry in the post timeline will show that the review has completed. Clicking the link will show which user completed the review.

[image]

I use a filter to only review posts in my general area of expertise. I may decide to edit a post to fix tags, fix code blocks or quotes, fix grammar, or rephrase a title for better exposure but lack expertise or the energy to totally improve a post. In this case, editing a post and then clicking <kbd>Skip</kbd> gives the next reviewer a chance.

I typically save <kbd>I'm Done</kbd> for questions that I feel very confident are off topic or totally unanswerable (that I've voted to close), or that I have edited and could reasonably attempt to answer.

You are correct that pressing the <kbd>Skip</kbd> button in First Posts has a different behavior than in other queues. In contrast, clicking <kbd>Skip</kbd> in Low Quality Posts prevents you from performing a review action on that post in the future.

I lack sufficient insight to be certain whether this is intended.

Comment: I had no idea what it's not possible to press Skip on a review in Triage and go back to it to review it anyway :O But out of curiosity I just tried it, and I was [not prevented from reviewing an item I had only just skipped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNCXu.png)

Comment: @Scratte Interesting, this appears to currently work for Low Quality Posts. I've edited my answer.

Comment: I've tried it with a review that wasn't an audit, and I can review that after a Skip as well :) I'll have to try it out in the other queue later on.

Answer (score -11):

Skipping should be used mainly after making edits that you want to leave in the review queue for someone else to review too. For more advice on reviewing see [How should I get started reviewing Late Answers and First Posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts)

*If you find yourself skipping most or all review queue questions, I would highly recommend, and you would get more mileage out of Stack Overflow if you browse or search [Top Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=interesting) or [Bountied Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=bounties) in your field of expertise, and answer those instead, rather than just browsing the review queue.*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225646/discussion-on-answer-by-dagelf-why-can-i-skip-a-review-item-after-i-edit-it).